# Why power is used for analysis in Microwave

Tags: microwave

Why power is used for analysis in Microwave where as voltage and current is used in low frequency analysis of electrical and electronics circuits.

Comment: Microwave oven? Microwave radio link?

Comment: Microwave electrical circuits

Comment: Your claim is simply not true. You might be confusing ABCD Matrix vs S-parameters with actual circuit design. But what you say is simply not true, so we can't answer your question.

Comment: I design on-chip circuits working at 40 GHz and I do use voltages and currents so your claim is indeed untrue. If you mention a certain RF power to an RF engineer, the experienced ones will ask you about the impedance into which that power exists. From Power and Impendance, one can calculate current and voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power is not used for analysis in microwave RF engineering. It is used commonly for measurement of signal level however. The motivation behind that may well be that thermal substitution power measurements are used to calibrate RF equipment back to DC measurements, so the earliest equipment was marked in power units, and that's the way the industry has worked since. In fact, we don't tend to work in power as such at all, but in \$20log_{10}(\frac{power}{mW})\$ (dBm).

For analysis, the concept of a wave, travelling along a transmission line, is perhaps the most useful for RF work. This consists of a co-travelling voltage wave and current wave. With suitable equipment, one can measure the voltage at some point on the line. If only one wave is present, the measured voltage is easy to relate to the voltage amplitude of the wave. If forward and reverse waves are present, the measured voltage will be from the sum of the two voltage waves. Measuring how they add up at different points on the line gives rise to the measurement of reflection VSWR, Voltage Standing Wave Ratio.